# Timezone in triggers at pipeline using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, triggers, timezone, jenkins-pipeline

I want to set timezone with trigger using pipeline.

I can set manually Build Triggers in Job config.

check `Build periodically`

Schedule :

```
0 0 * * *
TZ=Asia/Seoul
```

This works!

But in pipeline, below syntax works

```
pipeline {
  triggers {
    cron ('0 0 * * *')
  }
}
```

but here does not work.

`cron('0 0 * * *; TZ=Asia/Seoul')`

```
cron('''
  0 0 * * *
  TZ=Asia/Seoul
''')
```

```
cron('0 0 * * *')
cron('TZ=Asia/Seoul')
```

How can I set TZ with cron ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found it,

`cron('TZ=Asia/Seoul\n0 0 * * *')` works!

Comment: It does say in the plugin help: 

_Periodic tasks are normally executed at the scheduled time in the time zone of the Jenkins master JVM (currently UTC).This behavior can optionally be changed by specifying an alternative **time zone in the first line of the field**.Time zone specification starts with TZ=, followed by the ID of a time zone._. That would make the 3 initial attempts wrong and your answer consistent. You may wish to elaborate on your answer.

Comment: TZ=Europe/Kiev/H/5 20 * * * - doesn't wrong, can't find a current syntax

Comment: @AlexanderTunick it requires a line feed `\n` in a single line

Comment: To find the "ID of a time zone" see the "TZ identifier" column here for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones