# Schedule time on jenkins job is misbehaving even though cron seems right

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl, jenkins-cli

I have to build a job everyday at 09:29AM(UTC) but it's building at 11:AM ( UTC )
My cron is:
H 09 * * 1-7

What can be the cause if cron is not an issue? Or is it ?

Comment: Use `29 09 * * *` if you want it to be at exactly 9:29 AM. Using H is recommended though. Refer: [Jenkins cron syntax](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#cron-syntax) and try [Cron expression generator](https://crontab.cronhub.io/)

Comment: Relevant: [SO-63786427](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63786427/16586783), [Scheduled job builds are not triggering on time](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003237887-Scheduled-job-builds-are-not-triggering-on-time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option H takes the random min of the Hour. for a specific time 9:29 AM Cron Expression should be
`29 09 * * 1-7`

Also for timing can you confirm the Timezone and Daylight option settings.

Comment: The H symbol can be thought of as a random value over a range, but it actually is a hash of the job name, not a random function, so that the value remains stable for any given project.

Comment: @ArunKumarB Yes this is a hash value but not sure if it actually the Hash of Job Name

Comment: Reference: [Jenkins cron syntax](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#cron-syntax)